# Getting items that have more than one entry in the array with optimized code

Tags: javascript, performance, functional-programming, ecmascript-6, complexity

```js
let array = [1,7,2,2,3,7,4];
    
    while(array.length){
        // get last item
        let item = array.pop()
        
        // remove duplicates
        const filteredArray = array.filter(content => content!==item);
        
        // if filteredArray had duplicate items then log the item
        if ( filteredArray.length !== array.length) console.log(item)

        array = filteredArray

    }
```

This code is to find elements that have duplicate entries. Is this code optimized and what is the complexity or execution time of this.

is there a better way to do this , i am really stuck in understanding how to determine complexity

Answer (score 1):

**Time complexity is calculated as the worst case condition:**

Here the while loop **can loop "n" times max** ( case where there are no repeating elements )

each statement inside while loop **expect array.filter has complexity of 0(1)** so we can ignore it (Because these are just constant linear operations so complexity is always 0(1) )

While the **array.filter as a time complexity of 0(n-1)** [After removing last item] which when constants are removed becomes 0(n)

so the total time complexity of this equation becomes (while loop complexity * filter complexity) as they are nested loop operation

**so the final answer is 0(n^2)**

Also we should consider **space complexity** .

in the solution in question ,there is an intermittent variable called filteredArray which will have max length of "n" (in case of no duplicate element) so space complexity is 0(n) ( as it needs space in memory for each item in array)

so total space complexity will be

```
array (0(n)) + item(0(1)) + filteredArray(0(n)) = 0(n)
```

**Better solution:**

```js
    const arry = [1,7,2,2,3,7,4];
    
    const toFindDuplicates = arry => arry.filter((item, index, arr) => arr.indexOf(item) !== index)
    const duplicateElements = toFindDuplicates(arry);
    console.log(duplicateElements);
```

Has time complexity of **O(n^2)** due to indexof and filter functions

**Space complexity**

here tofindDuplicates is a function so 0(1) , duplicateElements will have max n/2 duplicates

```
array (0(n)) + toFindDuplicates 0(1) + duplicateElements  (0(n/2)) = 0(n)
```

**Best approach:**

```js
array = [1, 7, 2, 2, 3, 7, 4]
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
});

const duplicateEntries = array.filter((element, index, array) => {
    if (index !== 0) {
        const nextElement = array[index + 1]
        const previousElement = array[index - 1]
        return nextElement !== element && previousElement === element
    }
})

console.log(duplicateEntries)
```

**Here time complexity is**

```
array.sort(nlog(n)) + filter(n) = O(n)+O(nlogn) = O(nlogn)
```

**space complexity is :**

```
O(n/2) = O(n) which is the worst for duplicate entries
```

Comment: The example snippet you provide is \$O(n^2)\$ not \$O(n)\$ because you have `indexOf` inside the filter which must iterate the array to locate a duplicate, so if there are no duplicates for each item you check each item for a match. You can use a `set` to make the function \$O(n)(\$ eg `const a = new Set(), dups = []; array.forEach(item => a.has(item) ? dups.push(item) : a.add(item)); console.log(dups); // >> array of duplicated items`

Comment: @Blindman67 thank you so much so both the question and answer has the same time complexity ? there is no added benefit than space complexity for the approach in answer ?

Comment: @Blindman67 thanks for the help , updated the answer

Comment: the answer you mentioned is not working

Comment: Note the I named the array `array` rather than `arry`

Comment: @Blindman67 ya but the issue is that the out put prints 2,2,7

Comment: Any comments on the nlogn approach

Comment: For me it outputs `[2, 7]` You are correct using the sort and then locating neighboring duplicates has time \$O(nlogn)\$ and space \$O(n)\$

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @Blindman67 also one more question , you are using a.has() doesn't taht has O(n) complexity which makes your approach same as O(n^2)

Comment: `Set`, `Map`, `WeakSet`, and `WeakMap` are [hash maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) as are `Object`s and sparse `Array`s. A unique hash is generated from each entry which is then is used to index the entry. That makes hash maps \$O(1)\$ time for searches. Note that WC3 JS standard does not dictate how to implement Hash maps. The highly competitive vendor market has helped ensure that hash maps use the optimal algorithms in all but the most obscure implementations (browsers)

Answer (score 1):

Consider there may be cases where altering the input array is undesirable - be careful when calling methods like `pop` or `sort` as they modify the input array.

Another option is to use a [`Map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to store the counts of each number. This allows lookups of values in constant time. Then after the counts are stored in the map the entries in the map can be filtered to only those that have a value greater than 1 and mapped to get the key of those values.

A plain-old JavaScript object (i.e. POJO) could also be used (e.g. like in [this similar code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/176262/120114)). However [iteration order might not be preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) since the keys would be numeric.

In the snippet below note that `const` is used for all variables since they are never re-assigned. This can help avoid [accidental re-assignment and other bugs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653/244085).

```js
const array = [1, 7, 2, 2, 3, 7, 4];
const values = new Map();
for (const value of array) {
  values.set(value, (values.get(value) || 0) + 1);
}

const filteredValues = [...values].filter(([key, value]) => value > 1)
  .map(([k, v]) => k);
console.log(filteredValues)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer , could you explain why did you use value = new map() instead of values = [...array]

Comment: As was mentioned in [the comment by blindman67](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/266120/getting-items-that-have-more-than-one-entry-in-the-array-with-optimized-code/268101?noredirect=1#comment525880_266146) last month it is a hash map- it allows for lookups in constant time i.e. \$O(n)\$. Using `values = [...array]` would just copy the values into a new array